# If $a^n = 0$ for some $a \in R$, where R is a ring with unity, does that mean $R$ cannot be an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I think it cannot be an integral domain because $a\cdot a^{n-1} = 0$. But if $a=0$, this is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean it up a bit and it's true. Let $a\in R-\{0\}$, with $a^n=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now let $m$ be the minimal element of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $a^m=0$. Then we have that $a^{m-1}\cdot a=0$, but neither are $0$.

Comment: So does $a \in R$ - {0} mean the ring must not have 0? Or $a \neq 0$?

Comment: Here it means $a\neq 0$. Rings have $0$ as a part of their definition; we need an additive identity.

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is an integral domain and $a^n=0$ then $a=0$. If $a^n=0$ and $a\ne 0$ then $R$ cannot be an integral domain because $a\cdot a^{n-1}=0$. If $a^n=0$ and $a=0$ then we cannot determine whether $R$ is an integral domain or not because we always have $0^n=0$.